# Normalizing with "Relational Database Tools"

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

I am trying to use the [Relational Database Tools](http://raymondcho.net/RelationalDatabaseTools/RelationalDatabaseTools) to check if my schema is in Boyce-Codd Normal Form and to understand the relevant functional dependencies.

However, I am having trouble "converting" my schema to ABC etc. format as listed in the tool.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE train (
train_code SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT NOT NULL); 

CREATE TABLE journey (
journey_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
int INTEGER,
train_code REFERENCES train(train_code)); 

CREATE TABLE price (
journey_id REFERENCES journey(journey_id),
price INTEGER);
```

Is `A = train, B = journey`, and `C = price`, or is `A = train_code`, `B = name`, and `A → B` as the `train_code` determines the `name`?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question here? How to use the tool?

Comment: How the sample schema above translates into ABC etc in the tool so that I can understand the dependancies and whether the schema is in Boyce-Codd Normal form. :)

Comment: You've got it backwards.  You have to understand the dependencies before you go through normalization.  A tool has to do the same thing.  The tool can look at the existing data and make some pretty intelligent guesses about dependencies.  But there is no substitute for analyzing the subject matter to understand the rules.

Comment: Yeah. But I created a schema (just an example above) and want to understand it through the tool further. :) Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

1. The tool mentioned *does* not require trasforming your attributes into single letter identifier, you can use your identifiers (you just need to remove the ‘_’ character) like `journeyid`, `name`, etc. (and it transforms them automatically to uppercase).
2. Those kind of tools requires that you give a *single* relation, containing all the attributes, like R(traincode, name, int, journeyid, price) and then all the functional dependencies holding among them, like for instance `traincode -> name`, etc. Nobody but you can give those functional dependencies, since they describe the semantics of your data. So you need to understand what a functional dependency is, and describe those holding among the attributes of your problem.
3. Finally, this kind of systems will give you a decomposition of the single relation in several, *normalized*, relations.

Comment: Just to confirm: R(input all columns across all tables here). The relations are primary key --> column. What about references to other columns?

Comment: In the relational data model there is no concept of "reference to a column", so I don't understand your question. If you are asking about which functional dependencies fo define, I suppose that in your problem they are: traincode -> name; journeyid -> int, traincode; journeyid -> price (or something similar). If you are asking about the primary and foreign keys of the decomposed relations, then the primary key is determined by the dependencies used to produce the table, and the foreign keys are the attributes in a table which are primary keys in other tables.

Comment: Taking that last example. traincode; journeyid -> price. But what is the relation for journeyid here given it references another table. That was the piece I didn't fully understand here.

Comment: The tool also says R(A,B,C,AB,ABC). So does AB mean the table AB is a combination of columns from other tables only (namely A and B)?

Comment: @DinoAbraham, as I said, there is only a table, called "R", and in the example there are 5 different attributes, called A, B, C, AB and ABC. So these are just examples of names attributes, i.e. name of columns, with no particular meaning (they could have been called Name, Age, Address, etc. or anything else).

Comment: Understood. Is the tool just for one table at a time? I just tried plugging in the schema above and it seems to violate all the conditions except 1F.

Comment: @DinoAbraham, yes, you start a normalization process with a single, universal, table, containing all the attributes of your problem. There is a basic assumption behind the theory, called the “Universal Relation Assumption”, that basically say that every database schema, maybe with hundred of tables, should be in principle amenable to such unique relation, since all the attributes with the same name in the different relations have the same “meaning”. Such assumption has been disputed by some author.

Comment: So for the example above it would be: R(traincode, name, journeyid, int, price) as traincode is already in table 1/2, and journeyed is in table 2/3 but just needs to be written once. The relations are traincode -> name, journeyid -> int, journeyid -> traincode, traincode (table 1) -> traincode (table 2), journeyed -> price, journeyid (table 2) -> journeyid (table 3).
When I plug this into the tool it only satisfied 1NF, and violates all other NF’s. Maybe I have put the inputs incorrectly. Does it mean my schema is wrong? Also, what is a multivalued dependency? Is there one here?

Comment: @DinoAbraham, the relation is correct, the functional dependencies (not the relations!) should be only traincode -> name; journeyid -> int; journeyid -> traincode; journeyid -> price (the others are unuseful, since an attribute always determines itself). If you try this you discover that the relation is not in 3NF (it is in 2NF), and that the system (at the end of the printing) produces a decomposition in two relations. In your schema there are no multivalued dependencies (this is a topic which should require a few pages to be explained!).

Comment: Ah! I put traincode (table 1) -> traincode (table 2) as I thought you needed to declare dependancies between tables too? Is it okay that my schema is not in Boyce-Codd Normal form? The tool gives a very long list of non-trivial functional dependancies which to me seemed a bit odd hence I asked whether R(...) includes all tables. :) How do I filter just those dependancies that do not follow from other functional dependancies. I have 'code' in the train schema, and traincode in the journey schema (but they are the same thing) then should I relabel my schema so they are the same label?